# Adding an unused table after FROM changes retrieved data

Tags: sql

I am referring to the [Chinook database](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database), which i am using to learn SQLite.
This query retrieves the number of invoices for each CustomerId, as I wanted:

```
    select i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
    from invoices as i
    group by i.customerid
```

returns:

```
+------------+--------------------+
| CustomerId | count(i.invoiceid) |
+------------+--------------------+
|          1 |                  7 |
|          2 |                  7 |
|          3 |                  7 |
...
```

But as i was building a more complex query i observed something that i cannot explain:

```
    select i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
    from invoices as i, customers as c
    group by i.customerid
```

returns:

```
+------------+--------------------+
| CustomerId | count(i.invoiceid) |
+------------+--------------------+
|          1 |                413 |
|          2 |                413 |
|          3 |                413 |
...
```

Turns out 413 = 7 * 59, and 59 is the number of distinct CustomerID's.
There must be some fundamental SQL behavior that i am misunderstanding here, because I would expect no difference by adding "customers as c" in the "from" clause, since I am not using it yet.  Can anyone enlighten me here on what is happening?

Comment: You are performing a cartesian product as suggested below. You can also add a WHERE clause to apply correct join condition

Comment: ok, thank you all for making me realize i was doing a cross/cartesian join.  In he meantime I got it from this tutorial which recommends using that very syntax to do cross joins  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Only use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Your query is producing a Cartesian product of the rows in the two tables.  Then your aggregation counts the number of rows, for each customer, in the Cartesian product.

You need something like this:

```
select i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
from invoices i join
     customers c
     on i.customerid = c.customerid
group by i.customerid
```

Comment: thanks!  so what you wrote is the same as: 
```select i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
from invoices i 
group by i.customerid```
right?

Comment: @acromarco . . . Assuming that `customerid` is not duplicated in `customers` and all `customerid`s in `invoices` are in customers`.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a **cross join** which is the *cartesian product* of the rows of your 2 tables. You were right about the origin of the 413 value.
With a **cross join**, if table `A` has 5 rows and table `B` has 7 rows, it will produce a result of `5 * 7 = 35 rows`.

When joining tables, you then need to add a join condition which will filter unrelated rows (cross joins are rarely what you want):

```sql
SELECT i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
FROM invoices as i, customers as c
WHERE i.customerid = c.id    -- join condition
GROUP BY i.customerid
```

But the recommended syntax for join is explicit (no comma):

```sql
SELECT i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
FROM invoices as i
    JOIN customers as c       -- explicit join
    ON i.customerid = c.id    -- join condition
GROUP BY i.customerid
```

But this will perform an `INNER JOIN` by default which requires that rows from `invoices` table matches at least 1 row from `customers`, and vice-versa.
If you still want to display customers with 0 invoices, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` to keep rows from the *left table* (first one of the `FROM` clause) even if they have no match with the *right table*:

```sql
SELECT i.customerid, count(i.invoiceid)
FROM invoices as i
    LEFT JOIN customers as c  -- keep customers without invoices
    ON i.customerid = c.id    -- join condition, unchanged
GROUP BY i.customerid
```

Comment: ohhh, i never realized WHERE was an implicit join condition, now that makes so much more sense than how my teacher presented it!  Thanks a ton for that and the extra clarification on INNER vs LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @acromarco I teached about MySQL for a few years so I found ways to explain it, I'm glad it helped :-) Hit the upvote button if you found my answer helpful